# Is it okay to sum logistic regression coefficients of multiple models to find an "average" model?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

If I have N subsets of the data, each with the same variables, and run logistic regressions on each subset, could I then take an average of the coefficients found to find an "average" model?

For example, a very large dataset of sensor data that could be split into subsets by machine/device ID. Then, lots of regressions could be run in parallel for efficiency. At the end an average of each of the variable coefficients could be computed. This could then result in a general model for this type of machine/device. Is this completely unreasonable to do?

Comment: it's unreasonable because people have parallelised logistic regression before.  Why don't you specify the details of your actual problem, and people can suggest the algorithm to use.

Comment: I will disagree with @seanv507. It's true that there are probably more optimal ways of doing things if you want to invest time into getting a perfect solution, but this does not make your proposed approach unreasonable. I would submit that it is perfectly *reasonable*. It is not the *optimal* approach of all possible approaches, but it may be optimal given the price of your time as a developer. (assuming your sample size is still quite larger than your number of variables when you subset, this is).

Comment: @seanv507 Do you have any links where I can read more about how logistic regression has been parallelised?

Comment: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/boennecd/parglm/blob/master/vignettes/parglm.html, also vowpalwabbit, spark ml?

Comment: Is there reason to believe the different subsets represents the same distribution? Cause if the distributions are different, then averaging across them probably will result in considerable under fitting. And if the subsets are of the same distribution, then why not pool the data from all the subsets and fit the model on that?